# Error while running the command "npm install" while creating a RASA-NLU weather chatbot

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am creating a RASA-NLU weather chatbot.
This is the error that I get while running **npm install** and the folder "node_modules" doesn't get installed

```
(rasa_venv) PS E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master> npm install
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.4.4:  This package has been deprecated in favor of separate inclusion of a polyfill and regenerator-runtime (when needed). See the @babel/polyfill docs (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) for more information.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated ecstatic@3.3.2: This package is unmaintained and deprecated. See the GH Issue 259.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.9: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. 
Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'E:\\github\\NLP_ChatBot\\chatroom-master\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)     
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)     
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\rasa_venv\Scripts\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\rasa_venv\Scripts\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                                ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:399:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\github\\NLP_ChatBot\\chatroom-master\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-20T09_19_45_797Z-debug-0.log
```

Node.js and npm is installed

```
(rasa_venv) PS E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master> node -v
v16.14.2
(rasa_venv) PS E:\github\NLP_ChatBot\chatroom-master> npm -v
8.5.0
```

The contents of package.json are as follows:

```
{
  "name": "@scalableminds/chatroom",
  "version": "0.12.0",
  "license": "AGPL-3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.1",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.2.1",
    "react-markdown": "^3.3.0",
    "remark-breaks": "^1.0.0",
    "unfetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.106.3",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build src/index.js --out-file Chatroom.js",
    "watch": "parcel watch src/index.js --out-file Chatroom.js",
    "flow": "flow",
    "pretty": "prettier --write src/*",
    "prepare": "npm build",
    "serve": "http-server"
  },
  "main": "dist/Chatroom.js"
}
```

I am really not getting the exact issue. Kindly someone help me in resolving this. Stuck since 3 days :(

Answer (score 0):

Gyp requires Python and as you're on Windows..

- Install Python and make sure you include it in your PATH.
- Try running npm install with the --no-optional flag.
- Try downloading the windows-build-tools package.

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/03/27/node-gyp-windows/